# Все url перенаправляет на админку Django

Tags: python, django, админка

друзья. Я новичок и осваиваю Django. Создала суперпользователя, но теперь все мои url перенаправляются на страницу админки. Я выходила из нее, создавала новые страницы, но все-равно любые адреса приводят в админку. Что делать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Прежде всего что у вас прописано в urls.py? views.py? Скорее всего ошибка где-то там. Без более подробной информации это все конечно только предположения.

Comment: может в  .htaccess  что-то не так?, (если перенаправление было всегда).